# Vector Related Question

Tags: vectors, inner-products, constraints

The sum of two vectors $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is $\mathbf{C}$. Magnitude of vector $\mathbf{A}$ is twice that of vector $\mathbf{B}$. Then show that $\mathbf{C}$ cannot make an angle greater than $30^\circ$ with vector $\mathbf{A}$, without using differential calculus.

I tried to construct a perpendicular in the figure. But at least I am coming to the conclusion that the $\cos$ function on the angle between two vectors is less than $1/3$

Comment: Looks like what you meant by resultant is sum. [Resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) means other things.

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{\tx}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}\newcommand{\bx}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$$Using boldface $\bx{A},\bx{B},\bx{C}$ to denote vectors and $\tx{A},\tx{B},\tx{C}$ to denote their magnitude we have:

$$\bx{A} + \bx{B} = \bx{C}\tag{1}$$
$$\tx{A} = 2\tx{B}\tag{2}$$
Let's put $\alpha = \angle({\bx{A},\bx{C}})$ (the angle between $\bx{A}$ and $\bx{C}$) and likewise $\beta = \angle({\bx{A},\bx{B}})$.

So note that:

\begin{align*}
\tx{C}^2 &= \bx{C}\cdot\bx{C} \\ &=  (\bx{A}+\bx{B})\cdot(\bx{A}+\bx{B})   
\\ &= \tx{A}^2+\tx{B}^2+2\tx{A}\tx{B}\cos\beta\\ &= 5\tx{B}^2+4\tx{B}^2\cos\beta\tag{3}
\end{align*}

Now use the definition of the dot product and apply the relations $\text{(1),(2),(3)}$:

\begin{align*}
\cos\alpha &= \frac{\bx{A}\cdot\bx{C}}{\tx{A}\tx{C}}  \\  &= 
\frac{\bx{A}\cdot(\bx{A}+\bx{B})}{\tx{A}\sqrt{5\tx{B}^2+4\tx{B}^2\cos\beta}}  \\ &= \frac{\tx{A}^2+\tx{A}\tx{B}\cos\beta}{\tx{A}\sqrt{5\tx{B}^2+4\tx{B}^2\cos\beta}}  \\ &=
\frac{\tx{A}+\tx{B}\cos\beta}{\sqrt{5\tx{B}^2+4\tx{B}^2\cos\beta}}
\\ &= \frac{2\tx{B}+\tx{B}\cos\beta}{\sqrt{5\tx{B}^2+4\tx{B}^2\cos\beta}} \\ &=
\frac{2+\cos\beta}{\sqrt{5+4\cos\beta}}
\end{align*}

Now, we want to show that angle $\alpha$ can't exceed $30^\circ$ so let's assume by contradiction that:

$$\alpha \gt \frac{\pi}{6} \implies \cos\alpha \lt \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$

So we have:

$$
\frac{2+\cos\beta}{\sqrt{5+4\cos\beta}} < \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} 
$$

Since it's clear that the LHS's numerator is always positive (minimized at $2-1=1$) then we can safely square both sides:

\begin{aligned} 
\frac{4+\cos^2\beta+4\cos\beta}{5+4\cos\beta} < \frac{3}{4} &\implies 
 16+4\cos^2\beta+16\cos\beta<15+12\cos\beta 
\\ &\implies
 4\cos^2\beta+4\cos\beta+1 < 0  \\ &\implies (2\cos\beta+1)^2 < 0
\end{aligned}

Which is clearly never satisfied for any $\beta$. Therefore by contradiction we have shown that $\alpha \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$ $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

By at most two rotations, you can get the two vectors to be in the x-y plane, $\vec A=\hat{\vec x}$ and then $\vec B=-\hat{\vec x}\frac12\cos\varphi+\hat{\vec y}\frac12\sin\varphi$ so that $\vec C=\hat{\vec x}(1-\frac12\cos\varphi)+\hat{\vec y}\frac12\sin\varphi$

Using the cross product
$$\vec A\times\vec C=\hat{\vec z}\frac12\sin\varphi
=|\vec A||\vec C|\sin\vartheta\ \hat{\vec n}\\
\sin\vartheta=\frac{\frac12\sin\varphi}{(1)\sqrt{(1-\frac12\cos\varphi)^2+\frac14\sin^2\varphi}}\\
=\frac{\sin\varphi}{\sqrt{5-4\cos\varphi}}$$
Now we consider what are the possible ranges we need to inspect. We start with $\varphi\in(-\pi,+\pi]$. We do not have to check $\varphi\leqslant0$ because the angle subtended will just be equal in magnitude to the case where $\varphi\geqslant0$, and we also do not need to inspect $[\frac\pi2,\pi]$ because numerator is monotonically decreasing and denominator is monotonically increasing on that interval. Hence, we only have to inspect $\varphi\in(0,\pi/2)$. We just note here that $\varphi=0\implies\sin\vartheta=0\bigwedge\varphi=\pi/2\implies\sin\vartheta=1/\sqrt5$. Next, we apply the double angle formulæ and square everything,
$$\sin^2\vartheta (1+8\sin^2\frac\varphi2)=4\sin^2\frac\varphi2\cos^2\frac\varphi2\\
\text{Let }\chi=\sin^2\frac\varphi2\qquad\implies\qquad\sin^2\vartheta(1+8\chi)=4\chi(1-\chi)\\
(2\chi)^2+2(2\chi)(2\sin^2\vartheta-1)+\sin^2\vartheta=0$$
In this last equation, for most values of $\sin^2\vartheta$, there will be two roots. But for the stationary value of $\sin^2\vartheta,$ there will only be one repeated root. That is the case of the $0=$ Discriminant $=b^2-4ac$
$$(2\sin^2\vartheta-1)^2-\sin^2\vartheta=0\\
(2\sin^2\vartheta-1-\sin\vartheta)(2\sin^2\vartheta-1+\sin\vartheta)=0\\
(2\sin\vartheta+1)(\sin\vartheta-1)(2\sin\vartheta-1)(\sin\vartheta+1)=0\\
\sin\vartheta=-1,-\frac12,+\frac12,+1$$
We can immediately ignore the negative values because $\varphi\in(0,\pi/2)\implies\sin\vartheta>0$, and then we can reject $\sin\vartheta=+1$ because that gives a negative $\chi=\sin^2\frac\varphi2$, which is impossible in the real numbers. The only acceptable value is thus $\sin\vartheta_\text{max}=\dfrac12$ which, working backwards, comes from $\varphi=\dfrac\pi3$. This value is clearly the maximum because $0<\dfrac1{\sqrt5}<\dfrac12$
$$\sin\vartheta_\text{max}=\frac12\qquad\implies\qquad\vartheta_\text{max}=\frac\pi6=30^\circ$$
QED